# Check number of elements added to <div> dynamically

Tags: jquery

I am dynamically adding images inside a div using jQuery.

I have put an `alert()` after an element has been added successfully. Is there any way in jQuery to check if a list of elements has been added into a `div` tag?

Answer (score 3):

Try this -

```
$('div img').length;
```

Comment: if previously if he have images in that div what will happen with this

Comment: @PSR He can specify img class for example. `$('div img.newAdded').length;`

Answer (score 0):

Try to put global variable then increment this  value  by one in that method.Finally you will get count.There is no need of jQuery here

```
$(".selector").each(function(){
    var images = $(this).find("img");

});
```

Comment: sorry All , but i want to print Elements contained in div

Comment: There is no need of a global variable too